# Why git taggerdate is empty?

Tags: git, git-tag

I'm trying to sort `git tag`. Via Google search, I found a lot of posts are talking about `taggerdate`, but in my repo, `taggerdate` is always empty:

```
$ /usr/bin/git for-each-ref --format "%(refname) | %(subject)| %(taggerdate) | %(authordate)" refs/tags
refs/tags/hello | Merge branch 'featureY' into 'master'|  | Sun Jan 19 23:36:30 2020 -0800
refs/tags/v3.0 | Revert "aaaaaaa"|  | Wed Jul 3 15:09:20 2019 +0800
refs/tags/v4.0 | feat: a big enhancement|  | Wed Jul 3 15:12:49 2019 +0800
refs/tags/v5.0 | feat: hello world. Closed [RNWY-56].|  | Wed Jul 3 15:29:13 2019 +0800
refs/tags/v6.0 | feat: hello world. Closes [RNWY-56].|  | Wed Jul 3 15:29:13 2019 +0800
```

My git version is:

```
$ /usr/bin/git --version
git version 2.21.0 (Apple Git-120)
```

How `taggerdate` is created?

Comment: Looks like subject is empty, as well as taggerdate.

Comment: @evolutionxbox I don't see empty subjects, only empty taggerdates.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

These are lightweight tags created with `git tag` instead of  `git tag -a` (annotated tags). Lightweight tags don't have `taggerdate`. You can use `creatordate` format to extract either `taggerdate` from an annotated tag or `committerdate` from a lightweight tag.

See https://git-scm.com/docs/git-for-each-ref

Comment: You have a typo in `commiterdate`. Shoild be `committerdate`

Comment: @4d61726b Tnx, fixed.